# What dystopian TV show has kids running an underground newspaper?

Tags: story-identification, tv, post-apocalyptic, dystopia

I am trying to remember a TV series that I watched as a kid in the early 90's from either the 70's or 80's that involved a group of kids living in a grey (literally) dystopian world. They were running an underground newspaper or living in a newspaper factory (this is where the majority of the plot took place)- perhaps reading was no longer allowed or technology of any kind. There were no real adults around. Really bare sets and no footage outside of this space...is this small glimpse ringing any bells? I can't figure it out for the life of me!

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivors_(1975_TV_series) - the timescale is right but the details are pretty far off.

Answer (score 4):

**Possibly "Read All About It"**

According to [this article](http://www.toplessrobot.com/2012/03/8_forgotten_80s_live-action_childrens_sci-fi_serie.php):

> PBS has long been known for its innovative children's programming. Its educational juggernaut, Sesame Street, has been entertaining and educating for decades. While public television will always be remembered for Sesame Street, there was a myriad of other children's educational program in the early 80's including 3-2-1 Contact and The Electric Company. One example of a mating between education and science fiction was TV Ontario's Read All About It! The plot is based around three children, one of whom inherits a building called the coach house when their uncle dies. Of course, things not being quite as they seem, the children discover that the coach house is inhabited by two electronic beings: Otto the sentient typewriter, and Theta, an artificial intelligence who talks through displaying messages through a screen. The children decide to take the natural course of action when presented with a free building full of artificial life forms: start a f***ing newspaper.

However, the show is not set in a dystopia, and [the focus was as much about uncovering an alien conspiracy and bringing to life characters from books as it was about the newspaper itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_All_About_It!#Premise).

Answer (score 2):

I thought for a moment you were talking about [Press Gang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_Gang) which was an early Stephen Moffat (I wonder what he's doing now ?... ) production with Julie Sawalha and Dexter Fletcher.

Comment: Say what you want about [Uxbridge in the late 80s/eary 90s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_Gang#Location), but it was hardly post-apocalyptic.